# Django. 301 Redirect from old URL to new

Tags: django

**Hello!** Please tell me how to organize a redirect correctly.

There is an old version of the site and a new one. In the old version (another CMS, not Django) the objects have their own URL, in the new revised scheme, and the objects have a different URL.

In each object on the new site, there is a completed field with the old URL. In **model.py** it looks like this:

```
old_url = models.CharField('Old URL', blank=True, max_length=100)
```

I specifically moved the old url to a separate field. Or was it not necessary to do this?

**Question**. How to set up a redirect correctly, so that after going to the object using the old URL, the site visitor will be redirected to the new URL of this object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, I don't think writting `old_url` for each and every object is pretty inefficient. Instead you can implement [**`a custom 404 view`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/views/#error-views), and handle the redirection there.

I think you can create some regex or plain url maps to new url and redirect accordingly.

```
import re
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound

OLD_URL_MAP = { 'old_url_regex': 'new_url_path'}

def handler404(self, request):
    for old_re, new_url in OLD_URL_MAP.items():
        if re.match(old_re, request.path):
            return redirect(new_url, request.resolver_match.kwargs)
    return HttpResponseNotFound('not found')


# inside urls.py
handler404 = 'myapp.views.handler404'
```

Here I have used a map hard coded in python, you can create a model for that as well.

---

### Update

A costly solution is to use [**`middleware`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/). You can try like this:

```
import re
from django.urls import resolve

OLD_URL_MAP = { 'old_url_regex': 'new_url_path'}

class RerouteMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        try:
            resolve(request.path_info)  # trying to find if the current url exists in your django project. if not, it will throw exception.
        except:
           for old_re, new_url in OLD_URL_MAP.items():  # iterating through urls
             if re.match(old_re, request.path):
                return redirect(new_url, request.resolver_match.kwargs)
        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response
```

And add that middleware at the bottom of [**`MIDDLEWARE`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIDDLEWARE) settings.

FYI, its a regex based solution, assuming those urls are dynamic. Instead you can use plain text urls, but its up to you.

Comment: Hello, **ruddra**! Thanks for the answer. How to correctly add a line `handler404 = myapp.views.handler404` to urls.py? Sorry i didn't understand

Comment: @I.Z. Please see these documentations:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/urls/#handler404 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#error-handling

Comment: I feel stupid. There are no errors and does not work

Answer (score 1):

Use redirect() from django.shortcuts [the same library from where you import render]. Also, assuming, that the old_url contains only the relative url.
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

```
def someView(request):
    q = ~some queryset returning the current object~
    current_url = request.get_full_path().strip("http://www.example.com/")
    if q.old_url == current_url:
       redirect(q.new_url)
    else:
       pass
```

Remember, redirect() returns an HttpResponse.

Comment: Hello, **dotslash227**! Thanks for the answer. Sorry, but i did not understand a little how this works.
Where to place the code? Under what conditions should this start to work. Sorry again, I didn’t understand.

Comment: In your views.py, in which you handling the concerned view, you must have a queryset that would be return you the object with the old_url and new_url.
request.get_full.path() is a method that returns you the full current url of the current view in browser and strip the domain out of it, that will leave you with only the relative url path of the view.

Comment: You can then compare the relative path with the old_url attribute in the queryset and redirect using django.shortcuts.redirect method accordingly to the new url, present in your queryset.

Comment: Thank! I understood the explanations, but it did not work. I’ll try to figure it out.